# Making Sure A Random Key Is Unique (Testing Ideas)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am trying to implement a unique token on signin in a symfony 1.4 application.

I think this works but I am not really sure how to test it other than just throwing it into production.

Here is the implementation that I have so far.

```
// make sure that the key is not in the database on signin    
    do {
        // generate new keys
        $key = $this->generateRandomKey();
        // make sure random key is not used
        $key_check = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUserProfile')->checkDuplicateKey($key);    
    } while (count($key_check) < 1);
    ## miss this in original question
    Doctrine_Query::create()
              ->update('sfGuardUserProfile u')
              ->set('u.token_id', '?', $key)
              ->where('u.id = ?', $user->getId())
              ->execute();
```

Random Function

```
private function generateRandomKey($len = 20)
  {
    return base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
  }

static public function checkDuplicateKey($key) 
    {
        return Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select('u.token_id')
            ->from('sfGuardUserProfile u')
            ->where('u.token_id = ?')
            ->fetchOne(array($key), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    }
```

I think this works as I expect but I am not sure how to test it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If keeping track of the keys in a db you know if you can insert the key into the table where you store the keys, in which the key is setup as a field with a `unique` constraint, then the key is unique.

Comment: It does have to be unique but it is part of a signin function which updates a random token id. So it is updating the token id on each sign in. Updated the Question with the update query